# Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x^n)dx$

Tags: real-analysis

How to compute that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(x^n)dx$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{106}\int_0^{1/n^{2017}} f(x)dx$$ where $f$ is arbitrary integrable function on $[0,1]$

I have tried to swap the limit and integral sign, and get $\int_0^{\pi/2}\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(x^n)dx$, but there seems no further result can get.. And also the uniform convergence seemingly cannot be justified.

Comment: What is $f$ ? And why did swapping did not work ?

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main
page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730)
for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean $n^{106}$ or $n^{2016}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{(\pi/2)^n}\frac{\sin z}{z^{1-1/n}}\,dz=o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\underbrace{\int_{0}^{(\pi/2)^n}\frac{1-\cos z}{z^{2-1/n}}\,dz}_{O(1)}$$
holds by integration by parts and this gives that the first limit is zero. Try to apply this technique to the second limit, too.